# Cucumber - How to struct your tests steps?

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I'm currently learning cucumber and in very simple test, i had some doubts: 
"How is the best way to organize my StepClasses.

This is my .feature:

```
Feature: How many potatoes have in the sack

Scenario: I put one potato in the Bag
    Given the bag has 10 potatoes
    When I put 1 potato
    Then I should be told 11 potatoes

  Scenario: I remove one potato from the Bag
    Given the bag has 10 potatoes
    When I remove 1 potato
    Then I should be told 9 potatoes
```

And my StepClass:

public class Stepdefs {

```
private Integer potatoesInTheBag;

@Given("^the bag has 10 potatoes$")
public void the_bag_has_10_potatoes(){
    this.potatoesInTheBag=10;
}

@When("^I put 1 potato$")
public void i_put_one_potato(){
    this.potatoesInTheBag = potatoesInTheBag + 1;
}

@Then("^I should be told (\\d+) potatoes$")
public void i_should_be_told_potatoes(int potatoes) throws Exception {
    assertEquals(potatoesInTheBag.intValue(),potatoes);
}

@When("^I remove 1 potato$")
public void i_remove_one_potato(){
    this.potatoesInTheBag = potatoesInTheBag - 1;
}
```

}

This example works fine, but should i_remove_one_potato() stay in here, or in another step class ? 
Another question, if i want to use Scenario Outline, how i would do that in this case ? Because the answers would be different although the potato added/remove would be the same. 
There are good practices that guide this process of structuring your cucumber tests ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different opinions about how to structure feature files and step definitions, and a lot of it comes down to preference and the needs of the project.  All of my thoughts here are around system testing a large project through a browser, which might not be relevant to everyone.

That said, I've had the best luck with a 1-to-1 relationship between features and steps.  I like to have one step def to serve a single feature file, and avoid reusing steps as a primary strategy for keeping code DRY (that's what page objects are for!).  Occasionally it makes sense to reuse a step (e.g. Given I'm logged in), but my experience has been that it leads to building up these big libraries of very small, atomic steps, which are difficult to find, difficult to reuse, and drive the gherkin to be imperative to the extreme.

The obvious complaint with a 1-to-1 approach (other than violating [this anti-pattern](https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/anti-patterns/#feature-coupled-step-definitions) in the cucumber docs) is that it will result in duplicated code, but I've found that anything that you want to do more than once is probably a generic action that can be pushed down to a page object.  This leaves very little in the step definition, except code that is specific to the business rule being tested, which you shouldn't need to duplicate anyway.

So short answer, I would keep `i_remove_one_potato()` in the same class with other steps for that feature.  But like you said, your example is simple, so I'm guessing at what the needs of your project will eventually be.

For example outlines, you should be able to do something like

```
Scenario Outline: I add/remove potatoes from bag
Given the bag has <initial> potatoes
When I <add_remove> <delta> potatoes
Then I should be told <outcome> potatoes
Examples:
| add_remove | initial | delta  | outcome |
| add        | 10      | 1      | 11      |
| add        | 10      | 10     | 20      |
| remove     | 10      | 1      | 9       |
| remove     | 10      | 10     | 0       |
```

I try not to overdo it with scenario outlines though, this is probably taking it too far.  It can be tempting to boil an entire feature down into one programmatic table driven by generic steps, but at some point it becomes difficult to pull out what the individual business rules are.  When a single example starts failing, you have to tease the whole thing apart and figure out why the author picked the table values he did.  BDD tools are supposed to illuminate the feature, and large tables tend to obscure it.  For the example above, I probably should have split out add and remove into separate outlines, so I'm not mixing examples of different business rules together.

Some thoughts!  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As far the Step is relevant to the scenario to be tested it will be good to find the steps in single Step Class file. and for scenario outline it could be like: Add/Remove potatoes from bag.

:Use variables in scenario like 
Given the bag has "10" potatoes 
instead of one which you use it will help in long run.